# Empty struct to use with reflect.TypeOf

Tags: go

Whats the difference between `&Duck{}` and `(*Duck)(nil)`?
Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

ex:

```
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(&Duck{}) == reflect.TypeOf((*Duck)(nil)))//true
    fmt.Println(nil == (*Duck)(nil))//true
    fmt.Println(nil == &Duck{})//false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&Duck{}` points to a "Zero" struct instance, but it is most certainly not nil! You can assign values to it. You can't do all that to a nil pointer, regardless of the fact that they have the same type.

If you're just interested in checking types, I suppose a nil pointer is more efficient as there are no allocations of objects involved.

So it comes down to what exactly it is you want to do.